# Why are my Genius mixes on my mac different from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mac, music

I sync all my music with my iPhone. But for some reason the Genius mixes are different. This upset me because my Mac has an awesome Classic Rock mix and my iPhone doesn't.

**Is it possible to sync Genius playlists between my iPhone and my Mac?**

Comment: Do you sync **all the music and playlist** on the Mac with your iPhone? It could be that you are leaving out some bits when syncing, and hence the difference.

Comment: My iPhone broke ... heh. I'll gladly check and reply as soon as it's back.

Comment: Good luck while trying to bring your iPhone back to life...

Comment: It is set to sync all music and playlists. I get some really weird mixes on the iPhone, some with less than 5 songs.

Comment: Have you tried first resetting your iPhone (http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/17/reset-iphone-factory-settings/) and then syncing with iTunes?

Comment: I have. In fact, I have just restored it using an iCloud backup.